# How do i create a rule in mod_rewrite for months and days

Tags: regex, .htaccess, date, mod-rewrite

i'm using mod_rewrite. Part of my rule is to allowed days that range from 1 to 31...
The obvious rule will be:

```
(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31)
```

The same goes for months that range from 1 to 12

```
(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12)
```

Overall, my rule looks like

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/image/date(?:/(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12))?(?:/(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))?/?$ gallery/timeline.php?month=$1&day=$2 [L,QSA]
```

As you can see, the rule is ugly! Im convinced that there's is a better looking rule out here.
I've tried using the following for months

```
([0-9]{1,2})
```

But that matches one or two digits (0 through 99). I need a rule that matches 1 through 12 for months and 1 to 31 for days?

How do i create those 2 rules, for months and days ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For month:

```
[1-9]|1[0-2]
```

and for days:

```
[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]
```

But, these will allow for dates like `2/30` and `4/31` which are non-existent in practicality!

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/image/date(?:/([1-9]|1[0-2]))?(?:/([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?/?$ gallery/timeline.php?month=$1&day=$2 [L,QSA]
```